# Write To Flat File Store Serverside

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, office-365, data

Is there anyway to write to a .txt or other flat file that's stored on my SharePoint Online server? (Through Javascript preferably!). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't have access to the server resources.

If you create a provider hosted app, you could write to your server.